# Scraping all links using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all match reports links from the page but there is 'load more' button, and I don't want to use selenium. Is there any solution to collect all links without selenium.
Thanks in advance.

Here what I tried:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 import requests
 r=requests.get('https://www.iplt20.com/news/match-reports')
 soup = bs(r.text,'lxml')

 for match in soup.find_all('div',class_='latest-slider-wrap 
 position-relative'):
      links = match.find('a')
      print(links['href'])
```

Comment: as the load more is triggered via Ajax you'll have to use the requests library to fetch the results, not the html on the main page. you can check the script on this link https://www.iplt20.com/assets/js/news/news.js?v=1.7.7 and reproduce the line 67 of it on your python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.iplt20.com/news/match-reports"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("#div-match-report a:has(li)"):
    print(a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4014/tata-ipl-2024-match-11-lsg-vs-pbks-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4012/tata-ipl-2024-match-10-rcb-vs-kkr-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4011/tata-ipl-2024-match-09-rr-vs-dc-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4009/tata-ipl-2024-match-08-srh-vs-mi-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4007/tata-ipl-2024-match-07-csk-vs-gt-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4006/tata-ipl-2024-match-06-rcb-vs-pbks-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4004/tata-ipl-2024-match-05-gt-vs-mi-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4003/tata-ipl-2024-match-04-rr-vs-lsg-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4001/tata-ipl-2024-match-03-kkr-vs-srh-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/4000/tata-ipl-2024-match-02-pbks-vs-dc-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3999/tata-ipl-2024-match-01-csk-vs-rcb-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3976/tata-ipl-2023-final-csk-vs-gt-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3974/tata-ipl-2023-qualifier-2-gt-vs-mi-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3973/tata-ipl-2023-eliminator-lsg-vs-mi-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3972/tata-ipl-2023-qualifier-1-gt-vs-csk-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3971/tata-ipl-2023-match-70-rcb-vs-gt-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3970/tata-ipl-2023-match-69-mi-vs-srh-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3969/tata-ipl-2023-match-68-kkr-vs-lsg-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3968/tata-ipl-2023-match-67-dc-vs-csk-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3967/tata-ipl-2023-match-66-pbks-vs-rr-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3966/tata-ipl-2023-match-65-srh-vs-rcb-match-report
```

---

EDIT: To get all links you can use their Ajax pagination API:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://www.iplt20.com/add-more-match-report?page={page}&type=match-reports"

for page in range(1, 4):  # <-- adjust number of pages here
    print(f"{page=}")
    data = requests.get(api_url.format(page=page)).json()
    for d in data["newsResponce"]["data"]:
        print(f'https://www.iplt20.com/news/{d["id"]}/{d["titleUrlSegment"]}')
```

Prints:

```
...

page=2
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3964/tata-ipl-2023-match-64-pbks-vs-dc-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3963/tata-ipl-2023-match-63-lsg-vs-mi-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3962/tata-ipl-2023-match-62-gt-vs-srh-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3960/tata-ipl-2023-match-61-csk-vs-kkr-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3959/tata-ipl-2023-match-60-rr-vs-rcb-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3958/tata-ipl-2023-match-59-dc-vs-pbks-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3956/tata-ipl-2023-match-58-srh-vs-lsg-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3955/tata-ipl-2023-match-57-mi-vs-gt-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3953/tata-ipl-2023-match-56-kkr-vs-rr-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3952/tata-ipl-2023-match-55-csk-vs-dc-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3951/tata-ipl-2023-match-54-mi-vs-rcb-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3947/tata-ipl-2023-match-53-kkr-vs-pbks-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3946/tata-ipl-2023-match-52-rr-vs-srh-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3945/tata-ipl-2023-match-51-gt-vs-lsg-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3944/tata-ipl-2023-match-50-dc-vs-rcb-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3943/tata-ipl-2023-match-49-csk-vs-mi-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3942/tata-ipl-2023-match-48-rr-vs-gt-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3940/tata-ipl-2023-match-47-srh-vs-kkr-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3938/tata-ipl-2023-match-46-pbks-vs-mi-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3937/tata-ipl-2023-match-45-lsg-vs-csk-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3936/tata-ipl-2023-match-44-gt-vs-dc-match-report
page=3
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3934/tata-ipl-2023-match-43-lsg-vs-rcb-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3932/tata-ipl-2023-match-42-mi-vs-rr-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3931/tata-ipl-2023-match-41-csk-vs-pbks-match-report
https://www.iplt20.com/news/3930/tata-ipl-2023-match-40-dc-vs-srh-match-report

...
```

Comment: There are many more pages when you click 'Load More' button. I want links from all pages @Andrej Kesely

Comment: Where did you got api_url? @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @DJG Open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and click on Load More. You should see the URL there.